# Django not raising error when creating object without passing required fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model like this:

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    appId =models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    registeredUser = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True, blank=True)
```

When I go to Django Shell interface using python manage.py shell and try creating a Registration object without passing appId field (which is a required field) like this:

```
Registration.objects.create(registeredUser = userobject)
```

It creates a Registration object without giving me error **You can't set appId (a non-nullable field) to None!**.How is that happening?why is it not giving me error?What I am doing wrong or I am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Registration object's appID will have a value of '' (i.e. an empty string).

Also, have a look at [the docs for the null option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null), you'll see that absence of the null option does not mean that the field is non-nullable. Instead, `null=True` means that empty values are stored as NULL in the database.

If you want to avoid empty strings, either add a rule to that model field's validation, or via your forms.